# WSO2 Message Broker: Is it already possible to use MQTT?

Tags: wso2, mqtt, messagebroker, iot

Currently I'm interested in building a (small?) Internet of Things project. During research I found WSO2, an open source platform. I decided to use it and searched for developed projects. I found one decent [project](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/09/demonstration-on-architecture-of-internet-of-things-an-analysis/)!

This project uses MQTT as communication protocol, Raspberry Pi<->Message Broker, and Message Broker<->Complex Event Manager.

My questions are the following:

> 1) Does the current version of the WSO2 Message Broker (v2.2.0) already support MQTT? Because I can't find documentation of this version supporting MQTT.
>
> 2) According to some references the WSO2 Message Broker v3.x.x will support MQTT, is that correct and when will this version be released?
>
> 3) Are there any other possibilities to use the WSO2 platform components in combination with the MQTT protocol?
>
> 4) Are there any other documented Internet of Things projects that use the WSO2 platform?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/09/demonstration-on-architecture-of-internet-of-things-an-analysis/):

> The WSO2 MB team was working on adding MQTT support; WSO2’s Co-Founder
>   and CTO Paul Fremantle used this for MQTT interop test at EclipseCon,
>   in San Francisco in March 2014, where he presented a [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8lcYkKgDwI). We decided
>   that MQTT was the ideal message protocol for devices due to its open,
>   less message overhead nature.

According to [this article](http://techexplosives-pamod.blogspot.com/2014/05/mqtt-transport-architecture-wso2-mb-3x.html):

> Upcoming WSO2 Message Broker (MB) 3.x.x release will be supporting
>   MQTT in addition to AMQP.

There is a relevant source code in [this repository](https://github.com/dulichan/iot-ref-arch/tree/master/mqtt-input-event-adaptor/src/main/java/org/wso2/event/adaptor/mqtt).

Answer (score 3):

You could find more information on the WSO2 Message Broker architecture and capabilities through referring the article,

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/10/article-using-wso2-message-broker-as-a-scalable-mqtt-broker/

To answer to you questions,

MQTT will be supported from broker 3.0.0 version. and currently in RC stage. This will be released soon.

It provides seamless integration with other WSO2 products. i.e WSO2 CEP (Complex Event Processor), WSO2 ESB (Enterprise Service Bus).

Answer (score 2):

Until released, you can use the Beta version of WSO2 Message Broker 3.0.0 which supports MQTT to test out your project.

[WSO2 Message Broker 3.0.0 Beta](https://github.com/wso2/product-mb/releases/tag/v3.0.0-BETA)

The 2.2.0 version does not support MQTT.

Furthermore, since all WSO2 products are based on OSGI concept, you can integrate any of features available from any WSO2 product.

[Installing Features via the UI](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon440/Installing+Features+via+the+UI)

But if you're looking some simple integration, try integrating WSO2 ESB with MB using MQTT.

[WSO2 ESB MQTT Inbound Protocol](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/MQTT+Inbound+Protocol)